# Cinema 4d lite to After Effects pulling through white

Tags: after-effects, 3d, cinema4d

Can someone please help. I am new to Cinema 4d Lite and After Effects, when I am looking to colour tint in After effects its pulling the artwork through all white so I can't change the colour and render it out.

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks
Sam

[image]

[image]